# Php mysql conditional syntax inside query

Tags: php, mysql

```
$category = get_option('category');

// checks to see if subcategory is enabled in the option page  
if ( get_option('enable_subcategory') == 'y' ):   

  $subcategory = get_option('subcategory');

endif;

$qry = mysql_query("SELECT car,number FROM ".$table." 
                    WHERE category = '$category' AND subcategory = '$subcategory' 
                    ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 20");
```

How can i write the $qry so the " AND subcategory = '$subcategory' " will disappear if subcategory option isn't enable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Added `$subSql` var:

```
<?

  $category = get_option('category');

  if ( get_option('enable_subcategory') == 'y' ):   // checks to see if subcategory is enabled in the option page  

  $subcategory = get_option('subcategory');
  $subSql = "AND subcategory = '$subcategory'";

  endif;

  $qry = mysql_query("SELECT car,number FROM ".$table." WHERE category = '$category' $subSql ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 20");

?>
```

Comment: This looks interesting, and if there is no value $subSql is empty, cool;)

Comment: You can do it without the extra variable if you drop the $subcategory line and change the next line to $subSql = "AND subcategory = '" . get_option('subcategory') . "'";

Comment: @webmasters not empty nor cool. To be empty, this variable should be defined first